# How to get coefficient of x?

Tags: scipy, linear-regression

```
a = [10, 25, 30]

b = [13720000, 9090000, 3900000]

from scipy.stats import linregress

linregress(a, b)
```

How to alter the code to get the coefficient of the `x`?

Comment: The docs for linregress at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html have an example showing this.

Comment: Please show a minimal research effort before posting here

Answer (score 1):

Per the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html):

```
from scipy.stats import linregress

a = [10, 25, 30]

b = [13720000, 9090000, 3900000]

lr = linregress(a, b)
```

To query your results:

```
print(lr)
print(lr.slope)
```

Returns:

```
LinregressResult(slope=-448923.0769230769, intercept=18630000.0, rvalue=-0.9511220069021482, pvalue=0.1998650358314477, stderr=145758.73719079647)

-448923.0769230769
```